# Can I synchronize my iPad calendar with a similar online calendar?

Tags: ipad, calendar, google-calendar

My question is a little vague, I'm sorry. I'll try to make it clear.

I recently bought my iPad, and I fell in love with the calendar. I would like to start using it as my main calendar application, inputting all my future appointments and weekly tasks into it. I am afraid, however, that my iPad will become unavailable due to an empty battery, destruction etc. So what then?

Thus I wonder if Apple has some sort of online calendar to which I can sync my iPad calendar every time it's online or connected to a PC.

I'm very sceptical to syncing it with Google calendar, seeing as the calendars work a bit differently. In my GC I have layed out my tasts and appointments in "theme" separated colorcoded calendars. It seems my iPad will only let me work with one calendar, and the Google calendar will show up as a different calendar. I don't want it to work like that - rather I'd like to have full control from both the iPad and the synchronized online calendar.

If anyone understands what I'm after, I'd love an answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell Google Calendar which calenders to sync by using Google Sync. It's a bit convoluted, but once it's set up you shouldn't have to do it again. I've done it and use Google Calendar and my iPad exactly as you describe.

Google have the instructions here:

- [Using Google Sync with iOS Calendar](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=139206)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a free service, but many people really like Apple's Mobile Me service, which consists of mail, calendar, photo sharing, etc. that all works over the web. You can do a two month trial for free and see how it goes. http://www.apple.com/mobileme/

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you only get one calendar available on your iPad - did you enable the other calendars from your iPad with [m.google.com/sync](http://m.google.com/sync) ??